# Search a particular pattern from a file

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a text file with the below data..For example:test.txt

```
    20Jun@17:28 Ticket = [ABCDEF]
    21Jun@17:28 12345
    22Jun@17:28 This is a test line
    25Jun@17:28 Ticket = [ABCDEF]
    25Jun@17:28 Ticket = [123456]
    25Jun@17:28 This is a test line
    25Jun@17:28 Ticket = [DFG256]
    25Jun@17:28 Ticket = [ABCDEF]
```

I have chosen a variable as below to capture for todays entries.

```
    $date=get-date -format ddMMM
    $match=select-string -pattern $date $filename
```

This worked fine but the new requirement there is no need to capture each and every entry for today.

Just need to capture the lines which has the entries with the name Ticket in them.
So is there any way to get my pattern as below:

```
    25Jun@17:28 Ticket = [ABCDEF]
    $date+@+......'Ticket = ['......']' --is there something like this..
```

I have a very little knowledge on Regex :(

Answer (score 4):

Pattern for you is following:

```
"$date[@]\d+:\d+ Ticket"
```

Pattern for defined ticket is:

```
 "$date@\d+:\d+ Ticket = [[]ABCDEF[]]"
```

Comment: Hi @Garath ..this worked fine..but a small thing is that it is returning all the other lines too..

i just want the ones wich has the Ticket included in the line and the rest should be ignored.

Comment: @user2075017 you mark response as answer, do you have still this problem?

Comment: yah..it is still a problem..i just want the lines which has paterns 

  25Jun@17:28 Ticket = [ABCDEF]


Not the rest of them.
Any help please ?

Comment: @user2075017 added extended pattern

Comment: The same issue..it is picking up all the lines. :(

Comment: How you print results? I tested this locally

Comment: Hi @Garath I just used the command line select-string -pattern  "$date@\d+:\d+ Ticket = [[]ABCDEF[]]" $filename

The same issue

Any help ?

Comment: What is your input and output now?

Answer (score -1):

Second line should be:

```
$match=select-string -pattern $date $filename | where-object {$_ -match "\d\d\w\w\w.+Ticket"}
```

[image]